# Triggering Silverlight Prism command with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, command, hotkeys

Does anybody know whether one can trigger prism command with a shortcut? What I mean is I want to be able to define binding of a command to keyboard shortcut in declarative manner, like [ClientUI](http://intersoftpt.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/clientui-part-3-comprehensive-mvvm-framework-for-silverlight-development/) does:

[image: ClientUI key bindings]

Are there any opensource libraries for that purpose? Or maybe code samples?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478094/hotkey-commands-for-silverlight-in-mvvm) but I don't think that it answers mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created such gesture trigger. And I'd like to share it with you guys. Basically, it is `System.Windows.Interactivity` trigger which can parse gestures represented as strings. Usage is as simple as in ClientUI:

```
<UserControl>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <behaviors:KeystrokeCommandTrigger Command="{Binding SaveChangesCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+Shift+S" />
        <behaviors:KeystrokeCommandTrigger Command="{Binding RejectChangesCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+Shift+R" />
        <behaviors:KeystrokeCommandTrigger Command="{Binding NewItemCommand}" Gesture="Ins" />
        <behaviors:KeystrokeCommandTrigger Command="{Binding DeleteSelectedItemCommand}" Gesture="Del" />
        <behaviors:KeystrokeCommandTrigger Command="{Binding UploadSomethingCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+Shift+U" />
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</UserControl>
```

The code is on [pastie](http://pastie.org/1119798).

Answer (score 1):

You could write an attached behavior that has a listens to the KeyUp event and then calls the Command.  The complication comes in translating something like Gesture="Ctrl+Shift+A".  You would need to write a parser to figure out exactly what key combination that `string` represents.

Comment: So, no existing opensource solutions?

Comment: Not that I've been able to find.  Writing a simple behavior shouldn't be too complicated depending on how you handle the Gesture parameter.