# is there any out of the box feature in PRISM for Application level shortcuts

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, prism

Hi i was just wondering if there is any out of the box /hidden feature set in PRISM which helps me achieve application level shortcuts implemented. The only closes match i got was for leveraging WPF feature set in setting up a Application level shortcutss is  http://blogs.southworks.net/geoff/2011/03/15/wpfshortcutkeys/ through [Application Level shortcut keys in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319425/application-level-shortcut-keys-in-wpf)

any suggestions is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by application level shortcuts?  Do you mean (for instance) Ctrl-C for copy?  Or F1 for Help?

Comment: i mean like F1 and cntrl+Shift+P do a particular search!

Comment: It seems there's something in the MVVM toolkit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468362/how-do-i-associate-a-keypress-with-a-delegatecommand-in-composite-wpf

Comment: mine is a MVP application, lemme check if it could be helpful. Thanks Alfonso.

Answer (score 0):

In Prism you've got the CompositeCommand.  This is basically a container that can hold child commands.

Here's a link on the MS site describing how to use them: [CompositeCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921126%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

There's also a nice piece of code that handles all of the multi-key bindings.  it leverages System.Windows.Interactivity.  This will give you the F1/Cntrl+Shift+P functionality essentially for free.  You can find out about this here:
[Gesture Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353575/triggering-silverlight-prism-command-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)

This should give you what you're looking for.  And using very little code.