# Silverlight keyboard shortcut

Tags: silverlight, keyboard-shortcuts

I tried to implement keyboard shortcut into Silverlight and put the code:

```
private void link(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.A) {
        MessageBox.Show("alert message");
    }
}
```

This code works fine when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Is there any chance to set combination for 2 letters without `ModifierKeys`, e.g. <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353575/triggering-silverlight-prism-command-with-a-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: I do not think so A&T ,system cap one of them